# How many of the "top" users (by rep) are still active?

Tags: discussion, users

Just a nosey thought while I'm edging towards the 3k mark.

How many of the "top" users are still active on the site?
How many of have climbed to the heady heights of the 3k mark, to only then (at some point) leave the site?

In fact, while I'm asking, what's the retention rate like accross the entire rep spectrum?

Comment: What do you mean by active? Answer questions or do stuff on the site? I mostly leave the answering to you 'new' guys nowadays ;-)

Comment: Since you're about "policing" the site, *I'd* call that active.

Comment: Actually, in my mind, pretty much anything under "do stuff on the site" means "active". As long as you're *interacting* somehow and not just reading bits, don't even have to be visible - could just be a silent voter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Barring one or two people, all of them are very much active.

This [Data Explorer query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/502/list-of-users-with-rep-3000-and-their-last-accessed-dates) confirms it.

Comment: Ah, good job with that query! And it's good to see retention is so high. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @DMA5

Comment: Uhm @Sathya this query only shows the latest accessdate. It should be like the date of the last answer given (which isn't available I guess)

Comment: There are times when I don't answer anything (maybe because I don't know the answers), but I look around and go - so in that case wouldn't the `lastaccessdate` be changed ? I wrote the query with that assumption @Ivo

Comment: Well: Not answering != not active and Not visiting == not active. But... visiting != active. So this doesn't really help. :)